# Get the keyup event for each elements in dynamically generated html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

For single (first input box) I'm successfully get the keyup event but it's not working for every fields I want to calculate sum of all the fields and want to show them in total.

My code for javascript is here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var b = 1;
    $('#mon'+b).keyup(function() {
    alert('Monday');
      $('#mon'+b).each(function(){
          b++;
       });  
    alert(b);
  });
});
```

[image]);

I'm able to get the dynamic id like mon , mon1 , mon2.  And if I fire below code in console keyup event is works.

```
$('#mon2').keyup(function() {
    alert('Monday');
});
```

EDIT:-

```
var b = 1;
alert('Monday');
    $('#mon'+b).each(function(){
        $('#mon'+b).keyup(function() {
            b++;
            alert(b);
        });
    }); 
alert(b);
```

Edit :- 2  https://jsfiddle.net/b71a32qL/8/

Comment: Move `keyup` inside the `loop`

Comment: Can you share enough of your “*[mcve]*” code (including the HTML,  jQuery and CSS) that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @pedram I already try. but not working.

Comment: @DavidThomas i updating my Question.

Comment: What are you trying to get? I don't understand why you trying to get `b`, if you trying to get `value` you just need to use `each` not with dynamic `id`

Comment: @Pedram. I have to make dynamic id because I have mon counts , tue counts etc.
I have updated jsfiddle please check it. please tell me if I'm wrong with the logic.

Comment: @DavidThomas. I have updated my question with jsfiddle please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your js fiddle link.
You have to make two change,

Change 1 :-  (Add class `mon` in input type)

```
 <input type="number" step="any" name="mon1" id="mon1" class="mon cell-size" placeholder="mon">
```

Change 2 :- Replace your javascript with following javascript.

```
 $(document).on("keyup",'.mon', function(){
        var sum = 0;   
           alert('Monday');
             $('.mon').each(function(){
              var $value = this.value; 
                if($value){
                       sum+=parseFloat($value);              
                  }
              });    
           $('#mon_total').val(sum);
        });
```

So, through Jquery you can make total of each class `mon` using `each()` method.
Please Let me know that it's working or not ?

You can change your total with id `mon_total`.

Comment: Glad to here it works. 
Keep in mind never try to make selector (id) with mon1 , mon2 , mon3 etc. just use a class name with mon and use `each()` method for iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
// keyup event fire on all inputs its id starts with mon
$('input[id^="mon"]').keyup(function() {
var $sum = 0;
     $('input[id^="mon"]').each(function(){
           var $value = this.value; 
           if($value){
                 $sum+=parseFloat($value);              
           }  
     });
alert($sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to add events to dynamically created elements, use

```
var ele = '#mon'+b;
$(document).on('keyup',ele,function(){
    console.log('Monday');
})
```

Comment: Can you share enough of your “Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example” code (including the HTML, jQuery and CSS) that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = 1;
$(document).on("keyup",'#mon'+b, function(){       
    alert('Monday');
      $('#mon'+b).each(function(){
          b++;
       });  
    alert(b);
  });
```